# What can be done in CSS to prevent the website font-size from changing when the bowser font-size is larger?

Tags: css, browser, tailwind-css

Problem: I'm creating a website with Tailwind CSS. Everything is fine, but when I change the font size in my browser, the website font size overlaps and breaks the design.

**Note:**
All the other parts of the design are affected as well, not just the font size.

Any suggestions on how to fix it would be greatly appreciated:

Thanks a lot

Comment: Well u need to understand the different units such as px, rem and em. Check out the tailwind docs to understand what they use and how u can override as per your requirements

Comment: I am uisng rem everywhere,

Comment: rem changes the size according to browser root. Use px instead if u strictly need the dimensions

Comment: Ok, let me try, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `!important` tag in CSS whenever setting font size to override browser settings, however it would be better to make the website design resposive rather than setting certain sizes in stone

Comment: Tried, but it didn't work

Comment: In that case it must be because you're using either `em` or `rem`. In case of `rem` its the root `font-size` (`html`) you should try to override with `!important`